# Scatternd not supported

Tags: pytorch, onnx, tensorrt

I have a tensor with shape [1,100,34] which needs to be added with 2 tensors [1,100,17] shape at alternative indexes. Current Implementation is like this in pytorch.

```
kps[..., ::2] += xs.view(batch, K, 1).expand(batch, K, num_joints)
kps[..., 1::2] += ys.view(batch, K, 1).expand(batch, K, num_joints)
```

This gets successfully converted to onnx model using opset>=11. This is achieved using the scatternd operation. However, this operation is not yet supported in tensorrt. It fails with error

```
ERROR: INVALID_ARGUMENT: getPluginCreator could not find plugin ScatterND version 1
Parse Failed, Layers =  4447
In node -1 (importFallbackPluginImporter): UNSUPPORTED_NODE: Assertion failed: creator && "Plugin not found, are the plugin name, version, and namespace correct?"
```

Is there anyway to avoid converting this code to use scatternd operation in onnx. Or any other alternative workaround?

Answer (score 0):

ScatterND is now supported on Tensorrt > 8 versions.